# calculating the power in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the power as below but it is giving me 'bad operands type for binary operator '^'. I am guessing that it is a precedence issue but it still doesn't fix with inserting additional brackets

```
double pw = ((N - (df + 1))^2);
```

Comment: The `^` operator is not a power operator in java (it is bitwise xor). You need to use `java.lang.Math.pow(x, 2)` instead.

Comment: `^` does not signify exponentiation in java. [Here is a link to java operators table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: @Takendarkk, sure, I'd written the comment before I recall bitwise operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `java.lang.Math.pow(x,y)`

Example: `java.lang.Math.pow(2,3)` returns `8`

Answer (score 0):

See this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_pow.htm

```
java.lang.Math.pow(double a, double b)
```

You can use static import for this.